# Json to array issues when drawing C3 chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an json like this:

```
"result": {
    "axa.com.sg": 43,
    "globaltimes.cn": 81,
    "sh.fang.com": 109,
    "m.facebook.com": 83,
    "you.ctrip.com": 60,
    "bilibili.com": 53,
    "house.163.com": 59,
    "zhidao.baidu.com": 25,
    "news.qq.com": 38,
    "house.dbw.cn": 65
  },
```

And I wrote a for loop to pass it to the c3 chart in order to draw a table

```
    var top10 = data.result;
    var topTen3m = top10.threeMonths;
    ar topTen3mRes = Object.keys(topTen3m).map(function(i) { return topTen3m[i] });
    var topTen3mRes =[];
    for(var i in topTen3m)
    topTen3mRes.push(i,topTen3m[i]);
```

When i finish this code i realize that the array split in a wrong way, the result suppose to be  **[axa:com.sg :43, sh.fang.com:83 ...etc]** but it came out like **[axa:com.sg,43, sh.fang.com,83]**

How may i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty unclear what you exactly want to do. If you want an array from the JSON in the format **[axa.com.sg :43, sh.fang.com:83 ...etc]** , note that the element **axa.com.sg :43** will be a string(Please be clear if you want this as object).

To do this change your last line to

```
topTen3mRes.push(i+':'+topTen3m[i]);
```

And please clear what you want to achieve from

```
var topTen3m = top10.threeMonths;
    ar topTen3mRes = Object.keys(topTen3m).map(function(i) { return topTen3m[i] });
    var topTen3mRes =[];
```

as there is no key named **threeMonths** in result object and you are assigning a blank array after doing some operations on it.